# Android - Anyway to call notifyDataSetChanged in doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to updating hundred of records in doInBackground of AsyncTask. I want to update my listview at each 10 records. But we cannot call notifyDataSetChanged in doInBackground. So there are anyway to call notifyDataSetChanged in doInBackground?

I'm thinking about register a BroadcastReceiver. We send an Intent when finish each 10 records in doInBackground and notifyDataSetChanged will be called in BroadcastReceiver? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly what [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) is for - updating the UI (usually several times) during the task execution. You should notify the adapter there.

Answer (score 0):

`protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        _asyncTaskRunner.taskProgressUpdate();
    }`

Meu examplo